# Apache flink join: ".apply()" does not exist? (scala)

Tags: apache-flink

**Not an issue with flink, but missing a closing bracket!**

I am trying to follow the examples from the [1.16 (current, 2023-03-07) release](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.16/docs/dev/datastream/operators/joining/#window-join).

The example is this:

```
stream.join(otherStream)
    .where(<KeySelector>)
    .equalTo(<KeySelector>)
    .window(<WindowAssigner>)
    .apply(<JoinFunction>);
```

My code looks like this:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.assigners.SlidingEventTimeWindows

private val result = streamA.join(streamB)
    .where(new MySelector().getKey)
    .equalTo(new MySelector().getKey)
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(60), Time.minutes(60))
    .apply()  // <- function does not exist!
```

Intellij gives a couple of options there but no `apply` (see screenshot). Any ideas?

[image]

**build.sbt**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.12.12"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "apache-flink-example",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-streaming-scala_2.12" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connector-kafka" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-connectors" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-core" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-java8" % "0.10.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-quickstart" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-libraries" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.apache.flink" % "flink-clients" % "1.16.1",
    libraryDependencies += "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "4.0.6",
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods you see are the methods available for the `SlidingEventTimeWindows` class, because the function is not closed.

There is a parenthesis missing in the window function. Try this:

```
private val result = streamA.join(streamB)
    .where(new MySelector().getKey)
    .equalTo(new MySelector().getKey)
    .window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.minutes(60), Time.minutes(60))) //check the parenthesis
    .apply()
```

Comment: My bad! Thanks for that. I was so confused!